# File management iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I am looking for some free File management iPad app. It should be an offline file viewing app, with features to open common file types and also extract zip or rar files.

It should be exactly like Filer app, if u have used that, but without any file limitation..
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) may well be just what you are looking for. However it does not unarchive .rars. But it has great File Management, opens most files, and is just amazing. I use it on my iPad for reading journal articles from JSTOR at uni. Great markup tools too.

Also, if you use iCloud Drive and your iPad supports iOS 11, you can upgrade and one of the new features is the built in files app. 
You can look in .zip files on it, but I don’t know if it supports .rar archives

Comment: Yes, I know GoodReader , but guess I'll have to download the paid version, as the free one has certain limitations...I am lookinmg for some free app..

Comment: Ah, of course, I'm sorry, I should have read more closely. But in this case it is perhaps best to brace yourself and spend however little it is.